Constructing an algorithm to find the smallest log(log(n)) elements from an array of length n
I am a math student and I have been asked to help grade answer sheets for an Algorithms course as one of my professors is unwell. While I am quite familiar with combinatorial algorithms, I am not well versed in sorting/searching algorithms. One of the problems that has been asked is this one.
'Construct an algorithm to find the log(log(n)) smallest elements from an array of size n with the goal of minimising time complexity'.
The output need not be sorted. One just needs to zero in on the smallest log(log(n)) elements. I have been told by the professor that I am to grade based on worst case time complexity.
Sorting the array can be done in nlog(n) at worst. I have seen another post (Algorithm to find k smallest numbers in array of n items) that addresses this problem but some of the answers seem to be concerned with average time complexity and not worse case time complexity. This same post gives a method that does it in nlog(k). Is this lowest one can go or is there an O(n) algorithm? I would like to know the algorithm that has the least worst case time complexity.

There are O(n) worst-case algorithms (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect) but they are perhaps too difficult for a homework.

It's weird to ask for the smallest log(log n) elements in an array, because in practice log(log n) is always a small number -- even if log=log_2 and you have 2^64 elements in your array, then log(log n)=6. That means in practice the O(nk) algorithm will be comparable or faster than the O(n log k) algorithm, which will almost certainly be faster than the O(n) algorithm.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Any ol' quickselect for expected O(n) time, or median-of-medians quickselect for hard O(n) time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians

Does the min-heap sort (restricted to log(log(n)) steps) also do it in O(n) time? @MattTimmermans

@UmeshShankar using a max-heap of size log log n, it will take O(n log log log n) time, but as Paul explains it will always be much faster in practice, because log log log n <= 3.

@PaulHankin Mathematicians are a weird bunch. log log log n is good enough in practice you say? Sorry what's "practice"?
